# Which config files could disable the automatically starting ssh server, so a headless connect becomes impossible?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Which config files could disable the automatically starting ssh server, so a headless connect becomes impossible?

I need to know the config files that might interfere with the ssh server to normally start up at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the following commands (assuming you are running the last version of raspbian):

```
sudo systemctl stop sshd
sudo systemctl disable sshd
sudo systemctl mask sshd
```

`stop` Basically stops the service immediately. `disable` disables the service from starting at bootup. Additionally, `mask` will make it impossible to load the service.

Digging deeper into what each command does, on modern linux distributions there are configuration files for each service called unit files. They are stored (usually) in `/usr/lib/systemd`. These are basically the evolution of scripts to start services.

the `stop` command just calls the sshd.service unit file with a stop parameter, in order to shut down the server.
the `disable` (or `enable`) command removes(or creates) a symlink of the unit file in a directory where systemd looks into when booting services (usually, /etc/systemd/system).

`systemctl mask` creates a symlink to /dev/null instead of the unit file. That way the service cant be loaded.